# TFS build with Git repository

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

We are using Visual Studio Online (now Visual Studio Team Services) and our front end team have chosen Git as their repository. I want to implement CI for them so that every time they commit changes, I want to copy the flat html files to a different server. There is no solution (.sln) or project (.csproj) file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When the commit changes, or when they push changes?

Comment: When the changes are pushed to the Main branch

Comment: Are you using the hosted build controller, or your own build machine? Where is this other server? Does the account that is running the build have access to it, or is it public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

First, create a solution and a project.

Second, do this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/12/run-ci-builds-in-your-git-team-project.aspx

Third, you're going to have to add a post-build script that kicks off the xcopy. You're probably going to want to do this in PowerShell.

Comment: Will Git hooks be an option in this case?

Comment: Server side git hooks don't work with VSO, so no. You'll want to edit your build definition to make use of a post-build script.

Comment: Another option would be to manually write an MSBuild script that does the copy.